# Apple Maps Annotation on URL

Tags: url, ios6, annotations, apple-maps

How can I do to Introduce a custom title (annotation) on the new iOS 6 Maps on a URL.

{ http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino }

So how can I do to add custom title on a web link to this iOS 6 maps, and to be opened directly on the native maps app with custom title?

Answer (score -1):

You do not neccesarily need to use a custom URL. Apple added a class for their iOS 6 map framework called [MKMapItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html). The way you would use this class is to add the neccesary information you want on the map overlay when it's added to the maps app.

Here's an example:

```
MKPlacemark *placemark=[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:theCoordinatePlaceDictionaryRepresentation];
MKMapItem *item=[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[item setName:theCustomTitleYouWant];
[item setPhoneNumber:phoneNumberIfAny];
[item setUrl:aWebSiteToThePlaceToVisitIfAny];
[item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:aLaunchOptionDictionaryIfAny];
```

Check the keys for the launch option dictionary:

MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey;
MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey;
MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey;
MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey;
MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey;

It allows you to customize how the map looks and how it works.

Hope this helps.

Edit: this is relevant to native iOS code. You can find information about url linking [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for you're help,

But I just want to ask you please how can I add that?

It's on the head of the page or what? Because I don't want to open it in safari but in native iOS 6 Maps app, and I want to add that on an html page or php.

Thank you,